# Links, Controllers in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm starting with CI and I need some help. I'm trying to load some html pages with Ajax, this html files are stored in view folder, and I'm trying to acess this files using a controller and I have no success until now. I want to know, how I can acess this files and if the controller that i'm using it's correct or there is way better to do it.

**Controller**

```
class Router extends CI_Controller
{
     public function index($file)
     {
           $this->load->view($file);
     }
}
```

**Ajax**

```
var SampleFunction = function (router) {//router is my base_url() + '/router'
    var pageContentBody = $('.page-content .page-content-body');

    if ($("#startLoadTag")){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            url: router + '/SampleLink.html',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (html) {
                pageContentBody.html(html);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Until now I just get 404 not found.

Comment: not sure if you have have apache configured to remove index, but if not you should be hitting router+ '/index/SampleLink.html'

Comment: can't pass argument to `function index()` in codeigniter. Will treat the `/` as a method route. Simplest would be creating another function and using that in your ajax path

Comment: Ok, I fix the bugs. But now I have a big security breach on the system. If i change the HTML link name on Chrome and click on the link, the file are load. There is any away to block the change link name or something to increase the security. What you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chief problem here is the your index function will only be called if the URI is `/router/`.  The simplest solution is to name your method differently:

```
class Router extends CI_Controller {
     public function details($file) {
           $this->load->view($file);
     }
}
```

The URI for SampleLink.html would now look like: `/router/details/SampleLink.html`.  This is very simple, and should work without any problems.  Also, it shouldn't interfere with any other methods in that controller.

If you really don't like the longer URL then you can shorten it by implementing a `_remap()` method.  But if you do this, remember that you are overriding all of the default method-mapping behavior of the controller.

With this implementation, you could use the URI `/router/SampleLink.html`.  But that's all you could do.  No other methods in the controller would be accessible.

```
class Router extends CI_Controller {
     public function _remap($file) {
           $this->load->view($file);
     }
}
```

Finally, if you wanted to use the custom mapping for files, but keep the usual function-mapping behavior of the controller, you could do something like this:

```
class Router extends CI_Controller {

     public function _remap($method, $args=array()) {

           $callable = array($this, $method);

           if ($method[0] != '_' && is_callable($callable))
               // If $callable really is a usable method in this class, then
               // go ahead and invoke it with the given $args array.  Make sure
               // to exclude method names starting with '_', which are supposed to
               // be kept private and inaccessible from the web.
               call_user_func_array($callable, $args);
           else  
               // Otherwise, look for a view with the name $method.  Hopefully,
               // this will be something like "SampleLink.html", which exists in
               // the views folder.
               $this->load->view($method); 
     }

}
```